# Erro "Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons"

Tags: php, laravel

Quando faço o upload para a produção recebo estes erros:

> Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86 Warning: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/httpd/htdocs/telekobr/site/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 86

Estou usando Laravel 5.1 e o servidor esta com PHP5.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O [`putenv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) não é uma função do *Laravel*, apesar de estar sendo usada por ele, mensagens *"semelhantes"* a esta:

> Warning: ... has been disabled for security reasons

Indicam que o administrador do servidor desabilitou no `php.ini` alguma função ou classe especifica, no seu caso o `php.ini` deve estar algo como:

```
; This directive allows you to disable certain functions for security reasons.
; It receives a comma-delimited list of function names. This directive is
; *NOT* affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
; http://php.net/disable-functions
disable_functions=putenv
```

**A única maneira** de habilitar é editar e remover o `putenv` de `disable_functions`, se você não tiver acesso ao php.ini **só entrando em contato com a hospedagem** ou administrador do servidor.

Se tiver acesso basta deixar vazio, assim:

```
; This directive allows you to disable certain functions for security reasons.
; It receives a comma-delimited list of function names. This directive is
; *NOT* affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
; http://php.net/disable-functions
disable_functions=
```

**Geralmente** em Linux o `php.ini` para Apache esta localizado em (sendo php5.*):

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

No entanto se tiver duvidas da localização crie um arquivo `info.php` na pasta `htdocs` e abra via navegador `http://meusite/info.php` procure por `php.ini` com Ctrl+F ele vai mostrar a localização, agora o mais importante **delete** o `info.php` por questões de segurança, ele expõe dados sensíveis do servidor.

Então com a localização do `php.ini` correta abra o editor/processador de texto usando `sudo`/`su`, após editar e salvar reinicie o *Apache*, o comando é este (rode com `sudo`/`su`):

```
service apache2 restart
```

Se estiver usando *Xampp* as localizações mudam e isto que expliquei não se aplicam, o Xampp geralmente tem um painel de configuração que facilita tudo isto (não posso afirmar porque não uso).

> **Nota:**
>
> Para desabilitar uma função, por exemplo a função `mail`, usamos
> [`disable_functions`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) assim:
>
> ```
> disable_functions=mail
> ```
>
> E para desabilitar uma classe, por exemplo `Directory`, usamos [`disable_classes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-classes) assim:
>
> ```
> disable_classes=Directory
> ```

Comment: muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento, dei uma olhada no servidor e não achei este arquivo, vou entrar em contato com o suporte para alterarem. Valeu

Comment: @scooby o php.ini não fica solto em qualquer lugar, se você só tem acesso ao FTP nunca irá conseguir acessar, ainda mais se for um servidor SHARED (hospedagens comum), os unicos que podem acessar são os administradores do servidor(es)/estação(ões)

Comment: achei o arquivo php.ini porém não tenho permissão para edita-lo

Comment: acessei o servidor pelo programa Putty e loguei com meu usuário, depois usei o comando sudo e sudo -s, mas deu comando inválido. Depois de algumas tentativas não estou mais conseguindo acessar o servidor fica em timeout. Obrigado pela ajuda, vou entrar em contato com o suporte.

Comment: seria o ubuntu, sim eu ja utilizei esses comandos, entrei em contato com o suporte e eles tem q liberar mesmo essa permissão da função. Não posso alterar manualmente devido ao servidor ser compartilhado. Obrigado pela ajuda, foi muito útil vou marcar como resolvido.

Comment: @scooby por nada, obrigado ;)

Comment: fui intimado que eles não podem liberar esta função por questão de segurança, sabe de alguma alternativa para que funcione o env de meu site?

Comment: @scooby infelizmente é impossível, só trocando de framework mesmo ou de hospedagem, acho estranho este argumento deles, o `putenv` só será "inseguro" se eles liberarem algo sensivel de maneira forçado nas "variáveis de ambiente", o que me parece um baita vacilo da parte deles. Tem hospedagens em conta que suportam tudo no Brasil, talvez seja a hora de migrar.

Comment: obrigado, vou ter q mudar de hospedagem rs